# Use UrbanTerror with multiple screens on Windows

Tags: urban-terror

I recently got a second monitor, and the first time i started UrbanTerror with that new config, it stalled at intro screen and I had to reboot my computer.

Is there a way to configure [UrbanTerror](http://www.urbanterror.info/news/home/) to support multi-monitor setup ? Notice I do not ask for UrbanTerror top show on both screens, but rather to ensure it launches correctly on my main monitor even when I have more than one.

Comment: [this](http://forums.urbanterror.info/topic/1286-dual-monitors/) thread may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running in a window will get you up and playing again. Edit this config file: **UrbanTerror\q3ut4\q3config.cfg**

```
seta r_fullscreen "0"
seta r_customwidth "800"
seta r_customheight "600"
```

These settings switch off full-screen mode and run in an 800x600 window. You will probably want to increase the window size if you have space. Once you are running you can try pressing control-enter to switch back into full screen mode.

I also run dual-monitors and UT automatically runs full-screen on my primary display. There must be some subtle difference between our monitor configurations. I have a taskbar only on my primary display and extend my desktop onto the second one. If you're running dual-monitor software that spreads the taskbar across both screens (making Windows think your two displays are really one) then switching that kind of stuff off might help.